# Rails 4 i18n on activerecord attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rails-i18n

I'm wondering about something with Rails 4 and i18n. I've set up some attributes like this:

```
en:  
  activerecord:
    models:
      tutor: Tutor
    attributes:
      tutor:
        country: Country
        rate: Rate

ja:
  activerecord:
    models:
      tutor: チューター
    attributes:
      tutor:
        country: 国籍
        rate: 料金
```

In my view I am now doing the following:

```
<%= table_sort( t('activerecord.attributes.tutor.rate') ) %>
```

Is `activerecord.attributes.tutor.rate` correct or is there any shorter, better or preferred ways to translate table column names?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `human_attribute_name` method

```
Tutor.human_attribute_name :rate
```